# How to make the italics "more" bold

Tags: beamer

Please, could anyone help me - in this example below: how to make e.g. "f" in the equation "more" bold - to make the lines thicker? Now it is bold, but from my point of view it is not much different from the "not bold" letters (e.g. p). Thank you very much.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
  %\usetheme{Ilmenau}
    \usetheme{JuanLesPins}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathbfit}{OML}{cmm}{b}{it}

\newcommand{\DD}{\mathbb D}
\newcommand{\ff}{\mathbfit{f}}
\newcommand{\uu}{\mathbfit{u}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{PDE}
\begin{array}{rclrl}
-2 \nu \, \mbox{div\,} \DD(\uu) + \nabla p & = & \ff& \mbox{ in} & \Omega,   \\
                \mbox{div\,} \uu & = & 0 & \mbox{ in} & \Omega   \\
\end{array}
 \end{equation}               

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be best if you would choose a font which either has letters bold enough for your taste or use a lighter normal font.

If you don't find a font with these characteristics which you like, you could fake the boldness:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
  %\usetheme{Ilmenau}
    \usetheme{JuanLesPins}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfakebold}
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathbfit}{OML}{cmm}{b}{it}

\newcommand{\DD}{\mathbb D}
\newcommand{\ff}{\mathbfit{f}}
\newcommand{\uu}{\mathbfit{u}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{equation} \label{PDE}
\begin{array}{rclrl}
-2 \nu \, \mbox{div\,} \DD(\uu) + \nabla p & = & \ff \setBold\ff\unsetBold& \mbox{ in} & \Omega,   \\
                \mbox{div\,} \uu & = & 0 & \mbox{ in} & \Omega   \\
\end{array}
 \end{equation}               
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oh, great! Thank you very much!

Comment: @user70214 You're welcome!

Comment: I am sorry not to accept the answers formally by clicking - I have not known about it. So it was just a misunderstanding.

Comment: Now, I struggle in this same example with making the "p" in the first row italic (but not bold)   - \mathit does not work. Can you please help me?

Comment: @user70214 If you have a new question, please ask a new question. Please add a screenshot to your new question how you want the p to look like. It already *is* italic, you can see that from the slanted shape.

Comment: I am trying, but it  always writes:

Comment: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: I do not know what to do with that. The code is nearly the same as before (that was without any problem), so I do not see any problem now.

Comment: @user70214 Did you try to follow these instructions? Select all the code, then press on the `{}` button. Your question here has the same formatting problem, but another user fixed it for you.